# Show multiple line results for a related entity on a single line

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this simplified table structure :

[image]

If I do this standard query

```
SELECT p.Name as ProductName, ppl.Name as PersonName, pp.[Priority]
FROM Product p
    INNER JOIN ProductPeople pp ON pp.IdProduct = p.Id
    INNER JOIN People ppl ON pp.IdPerson = ppl.Id
```

I get this result :

[image]

However I would like to have this result :

[image]

What is the query for this?

Thanks!

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for the downvote and the very insightful comment.

Comment: @TabAlleman While conceptually this is pivot-ish, it doesn't really require that as PIVOTs are best for aggregations. This is a simple matter of multiple references for the current row. I don't think this question, even if fairly basic, deserves a downvote (and that is not directed at you since there is no direct correlation between votes and comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select from `ProductPeople INNER JOIN People` twice to get them on the same row:

```
SELECT p.Name as [ProductName],
       ppl1.Name as [PersonPriority1],
       ppl2.Name as [PersonPriority2]
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN ProductPeople pp1
        ON pp1.IdProduct = p.Id
        AND pp1.[Priority] = 1
INNER JOIN People ppl1
        ON pp1.IdPerson = ppl1.Id
INNER JOIN ProductPeople pp2
        ON pp2.IdProduct = p.Id
        AND pp2.[Priority] = 2
INNER JOIN People ppl2
        ON pp2.IdPerson = ppl2.Id;
```

The above assumes that there will always be a Priority2 Person. If that assumption is invalid and there are `ProductPeople` records that do not have a Priority2 Person assigned, then that would filter out the entire row. In that case you need a `LEFT JOIN` on the 2nd reference:

```
SELECT p.Name as [ProductName],
       ppl1.Name as [PersonPriority1],
       ppl2.Name as [PersonPriority2]
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN ProductPeople pp1
        ON pp1.IdProduct = p.Id
        AND pp1.[Priority] = 1
INNER JOIN People ppl1
        ON pp1.IdPerson = ppl1.Id
LEFT JOIN (
              ProductPeople pp2
   INNER JOIN People ppl2
           ON pp2.IdPerson = ppl2.Id
          )
       ON pp2.IdProduct = p.Id
      AND pp2.[Priority] = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
declare @product table (Id int, Name varchar(100))
insert into @product select 1, 'Product 1' union select 2, 'Product 2'

declare @ProductPeople table(IdProduct int, IdPerson int, Priority int)
insert into @ProductPeople
select 1, 1, 1 union select 1, 2, 2 union select 2, 1, 1 union select 2, 2, 2

declare @People table(Id int, Name varchar(100))
insert into @People select 1, 'Person1' union select 2, 'Person2'

select ProductName, [1] 'PersonPriority1', [2] 'PersonPriority2'
from
(
select pd.Name as ProductName, ppl.Name, pp.Priority from @People ppl
join @ProductPeople pp on pp.IdPerson = ppl.Id
join @product pd on pd.Id = pp.IdProduct
)t
pivot 
(
max(Name) for priority in ([1], [2]))pvt
```